# Invalid Types of block

Tags: magento, magento2

I've been failing, trying to add a custom block to my module.

I got the error message :

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid type of block: Cpy\AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne\Block\Form_lb
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Cpy\AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne\Block\Form_lb does not exist
```

Nevertheless the class is existing :

## Cpy/AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne/Block/Form_lb.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Cpy\AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Form_lb extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * DevisList constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Http $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Http $request
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
}
```

And here is the layout definition :

## Cpy/AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne/view/frontend/layout/acquisition_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>
        <title>Formulaire acquisition</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Cpy\AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne\Block\Form_lb" name="formlb" template="Aims_AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne::form/lb.phtml" cacheable="false" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: you flush the cache after create Form_lb class?

Comment: @BlackWhite I made a cache:clean

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out. My filename wasn't respecting the PSR convention. So the name Form_lb was invalid.

I had to rename `Form_lb` to `FormLb`then deleting the `generated/` and finally `bin/magento setup:upgrade`